# Connect to AWS VPN?

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, amazon-web-services

I am trying to connect to a VPN I created in AWS. I tried with `TunnelBlick` and the `AWS VPN Client`, but I couldn't succeed.

I am using OSX Monterrey, I installed `OpenVPN` with `brew`

I am getting the following error.

> Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:2: block-outside-dns (2.4.5)

Probably I am misconfiguring the file.

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote ###aws-vpn-url 443
remote-random-hostname
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
remote-cert-tls server
cipher AES-256-GCM
verb 3
<ca>
### CA
</ca>

<cert>
### Client Cert
</cert>

<key>
### Client Key
</key>


reneg-sec 0
```

Comment: AWS Client VPN might be more what you need, but beware of the price, it can add up quickly. Setting up software VPNs into AWS can be tricky, I've never tried it but I've read about it.

Comment: @Tim thank you for your message, finally I was able to connect without a vpn but setting up an ec2 in the public network which I gave access to the db

Comment: If you're using RDS you can simply tick the "make publicly available" box.

Comment: @Tim thanks for the comment. You are right, but I wanted to avoid public use to have a more secure schema. I created a VPC with public and private networks, the rds is on one of the private networks, the ec2 is on the public network, and I allow connections to this ec2 from my IP through ssh. Then the rds restrict its access to the subnetwork where the ec2 resides.

Comment: I think that "Make publicly available" just gives the RDS instance a public IP address. The security group that the RDS instance belongs to can whitelist a single IP address. But you're right, having it completely private via an EC2 instance does add additional security. However, it may be secure enough to whitelist one IP address and have user / password authentication.